# How to get product view count in NopCommerce?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I am using NopCommerce. I want to find top 10 most viewed products of particular category.
For that I have created new table named `ProductViewDetails`. I want to join "Product" table with this table to store product view count.

So, how can I get the number ff views for particular product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to write logic for increasing product view count at following `action`

```
public ActionResult Product(int productId)
        {
      _productViewService.IncreaseViewCount(productId);
}
```

In service you need to write actual logic to increase view count

```
 public virtual void IncreaseViewCount(int pId)
{
  //here get entry for product view details if exists or create new one
  //then increase count by 1
}
```